# cannot range over eagle (type interface {}) with "encoding/json"

Tags: json, go

I have the following code, I would like range over all the elements or access one element like `birds["eagle"["quote"][2]` but I cannot figure it out

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    birdJson := `{"birds": {"pigeon": {"quotes": "love the pigeons"}, "eagle": {"quotes": ["bird of prey", "soar like an eagle", "eagle has no fear"]}}}`

    var result map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(birdJson), &result)
    birds := result["birds"].(map[string]interface{})

    fmt.Printf("%v\n",birds)
    eagle := birds["eagle"]

    for key, value := range eagle {
        fmt.Println(key, value.(string))
    }
}
```

[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Nwb0f6cuDUG)

Comment: You must typeassert like you did for birds.

Comment: Thank you all, I was not used to the `interface{}` thing, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few issues:

```
eagle := birds["eagle"] //eagle is of type interface{}
```

so cast it into map:

```
eagle := birds["eagle"].(map[string]interface{})
```

Now you can iterate over it:

```
for key, value := range eagle { 
        for _, e := range value.([]interface{}){
         fmt.Println(key, e.(string))
        }
    }
```

value is again interface here.  So first cast to []interface{} and then to string.
Here is the full working code:
https://play.golang.org/p/Bdnwit1wBYh